# How to convert all this node code to promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I use the following code and I want to convert it to promise, so I've started to promisify child process but my question is how to convert all to promise,
I need to divide the code to additional (see comments) methods
when I use the code as is its working OK.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    fs = require('fs').


module.exports = {
    createNew: function () {
        fs.readFile("c://test.txt", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }

            // 1. from Here to needed to divide to new method
            //    which just return cmd value

            var fileKeyValObj = {};
            data.split("\n").forEach(function (element) {
                var sep = element.indexOf(':');

            });

            var cmd = fileKeyValObj['name'];

            // 2. this code should be in additional method

            if (typeof cmd !== 'undefined') {
                var exec = Promise.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
                var childProcess = exec(cmd).spread(function (stdout, stderr) {

                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                });

            }
        });
    },
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? Your code is poorly written and, as such, it is difficult to see your ultimate goal.

Comment: @royhowie- what do you mean by poorly writen ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Add further comments to explain each step. For example, you use `Promise.spread`, but it appears that `cmd` is a single command, not an array of commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bluebird `.promisifyAll()` function on fs as well as your exec command, then chain them together:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
var exec = Promise.promisify(require('child_process').exec);


var parseFile = function(data) {
  var fileKeyValObj = {};

  data.split('\n').forEach(function (element) {
      var sep = element.indexOf(':');
      var cmdValue = element.substring(sep + 2);
      fileKeyValObj[element.substr(3, sep)] = cmdValue;
  });

  return fileKeyValObj['name'];
};


module.exports = {
  createNew: function () {
    return fs.readFileAsync('c://test.txt', 'utf8')
      .then(parseFile)
      .then(exec)
      .spread(function(stdout, stderr) {
        // do stuff here with stdout and stderr

        if (stderr) {
          throw new Error('An Error Occurred.');
        }

        // anything returned will be returned on the next item in the chain.
        return stdout;
      });
    },
};
```

**How to call function from another module:**

```
var myModule = require('./path/to/module');

myModule.createNew().then(function(data) {
  // this is the data returned from the final step of the createNew promise chain.
  console.log(data);
}).catch(function(err) {
  // catch and handle errors here instead.
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks 1+ assume that I want to put the following in diffrent method ,how should i use it than?    data.split("\n").forEach(function (element) {
              var sep = element.indexOf(':');
              var cmdValue = element.substring(sep + 2);
              fileKeyValObj[element.substr(3, sep)] = cmdValue;
            });

            var cmd = fileKeyValObj['name'];

Comment: Thanks almost :) questions why you put the following ?var execCommand = function(cmd) {
  return exec(cmd);
};

Comment: 2. how would you handle error,I shouldn't use reject and resolve in this case?

Comment: 1. Your right, it was not required, you can pipe it directly to the exec function and it should still work.

2. Errors should be caught in the final catch statement. You can raise an error anywhere in the promise chain by throwing and error with ```throw```.

Comment: Ok Thanks,last 2 questions :) before I mark is an answer ? how would you trow and error (best practice ) 2. how would you call to this functionality(createNew) from other module and catch exception if any was raised,Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. I have provided an example of how you could throw an error in the promise chain, in the example I gave it is throw if stderr is not null.

2. Example provided of how to import and call the function from another module. As the createNew function returns the promise chain you can extend it in your other modules, as well as catch errors and react accordingly.

Comment: @JhonDree what is the point of `.forEach` (going through every line) and storing the data in `fileKeyValObj` if you're only after a single value (`fileKeyvalObj['name']`)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Promise.promisifyAll` on `fs`.

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'

let fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))
let exec = Promise.promisify(require('child_process').exec)

function mapCommands (file) {
    return file.split('\n').reduce((p, c) => {
        let separation = c.indexOf(':')
        p[c.slice(3, separation)] = c.slice(separation + 2)
        return p
    }, {})    
}

function execCommands (obj) {
    let commands = []
    for (let key in obj) {
        let cmd = exec(obj[key])
        commands.push(cmd)
    }
    return Promise.all(commands)
}

export default {
    createNew () {
        fs.readFileAsync('C://test.txt', 'utf8')
        .then(mapCommands)
        .then(execCommands)
        .then(() => {
            // success; all commands executed
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)    // handle err
        }) 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks 1+ , I want to test the code should I use additional library for it(Ecma 6)?

Comment: I used some es6 syntax, but you can easily switch back to es5 by using `function () {}` instead of `() => ()`, `var Promise = require('bluebird')`, and `createNew: function () {}`. If you want it to "just work," you can use [babel.js](http://babeljs.io).

Comment: in the last then...(where you put sucess )\

Comment: I try to do that without success maybe I should Use some CO.. modules?